# IIS 7.0 Multiple Domain Site Bindings

Tags: iis, iis-7, binding, hosting, dns

I've got three web sites each with its own domain going to my one Windows Server 2008 IIS 7.0 web server.

- `example1.com`
- `example2.com`
- `example3.com`

The site bindings for each:

[IIS 7.0 Site Bindings example1.com http://img371.imageshack.us/img371/4215/example1pf4.gif](http://img371.imageshack.us/img371/4215/example1pf4.gif)

[IIS 7.0 Site Bindings example2.com http://img371.imageshack.us/img371/2567/example2xx0.gif](http://img371.imageshack.us/img371/2567/example2xx0.gif)

[IIS 7.0 Site Bindings example3.com http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/8186/example3rh9.gif](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/8186/example3rh9.gif)

When I navigate to `example1.com`, then I see my *example1* web site.

When I navigate to `example2.com`, then I see my *example2* web site.

But, when I navigate to `example3.com`, I see my *example1* web site--not the *example3* web site I expect.

What's going on?  Why might `example2.com` work, but `example3.com` fail?

---

<del>Issue resolved!</del>

I removed and then recreated the *example3.com* web site within IIS and it's now working.

I didn't change anything.  It either originally had a simple typo or the act of recreating it just happened to fix a hiccup within IIS.

---

<del>It's stopped working again after I setup additional redirects within IIS forcing web sites to use sub domains:</del>

`http://example1.com/` redirects to `http://www.example1.com/`

I've again removed and then recreated the *example3.com* web sites; I've reset IIS; I've rebooted the server.  It's still not working correctly.

---

I've figured it out.  It's not an IIS issue.  It's a DNS issue.

The `example3.com` traffic is for some reason directed to a web server at a different company. THEY serve up a page with only an HTML frame on it.  That frame loads a page with the address `http://example3.example1.com`.  That's what I need to handle on MY web server.

Answer (score 1):

I would validate that you have example3.com pointing to the proper location on disk.  Also ensure that it is not stopped.

The fallback to example1 is due to the binding entry with no header value.

Comment: I've changed the web site "with no header value" to simply redirect to http://www.example1.com/, but visiting http://example3.com/ or http://www.example3.com/ loads the example1 web site without doing the redirect!  It keeps http://example3.com/ in the address bar.

Comment: That would lead me to believe that the root path for the website is incorrect, as with the domain name staying the same, it shows that it is getting the header value.

Comment: The Physical Path is set to C:\inetpub\example3 a real folder with a default.html file there.  And, "default.html" is a Default Document for that Site.